# if $\sup S=+ \infty$ , then there is a sequence of points $s_n \in S$ such that $s_n \rightarrow +\infty $

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $\sup S=+ \infty$ , then there is a sequence of points $s_n \in S$ such that $s_n \rightarrow +\infty $.

Comment: please help me to solve this question

Comment: Probably the reason why the question was down-voted and why some people have voted to close it is that questions posted here should not be expressed in language suitable for assigning homework.  It can make people wonder if you copied a question without understanding it. You can ask for help understanding a question or you can say what difficulties you had with it. People who vote to close a question on those grounds ought to explain all of that here, but usually they don't. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Let $c > 0$. We wish to show that $\exists x \in S\mid x > c$. Suppose that such $x$ does not exist. Then $c$ provides an upper bound to $S$, which contradicts the fact that $+\infty$ is its least upper bound. Therefore, we can choose $c = 0,1,2,3,4,5,\dots$ and form the corresponding $x$'s into a sequence that $\to \infty$.

Comment: @Henry...thanks but i need more explanation/.....please

Comment: @bujji Which part does you not understand?

Comment: for choosing c values

Comment: @bujji Choose $c = 0$ then $\exists x_0 \in S\mid x_0 > 0$. Then choose $c = 1$ so that $\exists x_1 \in S\mid x_1 > 1$ and so on.

Comment: @heny...thanks..but still i am confusing

Comment: @Henry..If u dont mind i need proper answer...

Comment: @bujji This is the type of answer you are going to find on analysis textbooks.

Comment: i have only one N.P.bali but i dint find the answer..can u please provide me this